# Calculate the ratio of specific columns with the same values as other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame `df` as follows:

```
   id  target1  target2  value1  value2  value3
0   1        1       -1     NaN     0.0     NaN
1   2       -1        1     1.0     1.0     1.0
2   3        1       -1     1.0    -1.0    -1.0
3   4        1       -1     1.0     1.0     1.0
4   5       -1       -1    -1.0     1.0     1.0
5   6       -1       -1     1.0    -1.0    -1.0
6   7       -1        1    -1.0     NaN     1.0
```

Let's say for columns `target1` and `target2`, I hope to know which value columns (**value1, value2, value3, value4,** etc.) have more same values with them respectively. Please note if `value` column's values are `NaN`s, it will not be included in the comparison.

For example, for `target1-value1`, we find id is 3, 4, 5 and 7, they have same values, so the ratio is `4/6 = 0.666667` (`id==1` will not be included since `value1` is `NaN` for that cell). Same logic for other columns.

So my question is how could I get the expected result below with Pandas?

```
  value_cols   target1   target2
0     value1  0.666667  0.333333
1     value2  0.333333  0.500000
2     value3  0.333333  0.666667
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `apply`. The general idea is to iterate over the "target" columns and count the number of matches with "value" columns (with `eq` on axis + `sum`); then find the ratio by dividing the totals found with the number of non-NaN rows for each "value" column:

```
val_cols = ['value1','value2','value3']
totals = df[val_cols].notna().sum()
out = df[['target1','target2']].apply(lambda col: df[val_cols].eq(col, axis=0).sum() / totals)

# out.rename_axis('value_cols').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         target1   target2
value1  0.666667  0.333333
value2  0.333333  0.500000
value3  0.333333  0.666667
```